# list raw files in lightroom

Tags: post-processing, lightroom-5

Is there way to retrieve a list of raw file names which correspond to a given filter, in Adobe Photoshop Lightroom? If I want to export files, I only see the way to convert them to jpg images, but cannot find a way to export raw files without development settings so far.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I figured it out. In the export settings dialog, select Original in Image Format selection box. That's it!